# The prediction for an image classification algorithm is not printing

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, image-processing, keras

I have trained a model for image classification in Jupyter Notebook, and have gotten to the point of testing an image to see if it is "Pasta = 0" or "Pizza = 1". The model is fitting at an accuracy between 70 and 80 percent on average for most epochs.

However, the value prediction is not printing. All that happens when the test image is processed is that the processing is shown as "Completed" with the time it took per step. There is no "Pasta" or "Pizza" printed.

Here is the code I have so far:

```
#Import all libraries needed.

import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow import keras
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense, Flatten, Conv2D, MaxPooling2D, Dropout
from tensorflow.keras import layers
from keras.utils import to_categorical
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator
from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing import image
from tensorflow.keras.optimizers import RMSprop
import cv2
import os



plt.style.use('fivethirtyeight')

img = image.load_img("D:/ML Datasets/FoodImageClassification/Training Data/Pizza/Pizza - Wikipedia.jpg")

plt.imshow(img)


cv2.imread("D:/ML Datasets/FoodImageClassification/Training Data/Pizza/Pizza - Wikipedia.jpg")

cv2.imread("D:/ML Datasets/FoodImageClassification/Training Data/Pizza/Pizza - Wikipedia.jpg").shape

#Training and Validation
train = ImageDataGenerator(rescale = 1/255)
validation = ImageDataGenerator(rescale = 1/255)

train_dataset = train.flow_from_directory('D:/ML Datasets/FoodImageClassification/Training Data/',target_size = (200,200),
                                          batch_size = 4,
                                          class_mode = 'binary')


validation_dataset = train.flow_from_directory('D:/ML Datasets/FoodImageClassification/Testing Data/',target_size = (200,200),
                                          batch_size = 4,
                                          class_mode = 'binary')




train_dataset.class_indices   #This returns {'Pasta': 0, 'Pizza': 1}



train_dataset.classes

model = tf.keras.models.Sequential([tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(16,(3,3),activation = 'relu',input_shape = (200,200,3)),
                                    tf.keras.layers.MaxPool2D(2,2),
                                    #
                                    tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(32,(3,3),activation = 'relu'),
                                    tf.keras.layers.MaxPool2D(2,2),
                                    #
                                    tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(32,(3,3),activation = 'relu'),
                                    tf.keras.layers.MaxPool2D(2,2),
                                    ##
                                    tf.keras.layers.Flatten(),
                                    ##
                                    tf.keras.layers.Flatten(),
                                    ##
                                    tf.keras.layers.Dense(512,activation='relu'),
                                    ##
                                    tf.keras.layers.Dense(1,activation='sigmoid'),
                                    ##
                                    tf.keras.layers.Dense(1,activation='softmax'),
                                    ##
                                    tf.keras.layers.Dense(1,activation='sigmoid')
                                   ])


model.compile(loss = 'binary_crossentropy',
             optimizer = RMSprop(learning_rate=0.30),
             metrics = ['accuracy'])



model_fit = model.fit(train_dataset,
                     steps_per_epoch = 5,
                     epochs = 50,
                     validation_data = validation_dataset)



from skimage.transform import resize

img = image.load_img('D://ML Datasets/FoodImageClassification/Testing Data/Pasta/Garlic Butter Parmesan Pasta Recipe.jpg')



newsize = (200, 200)
img = img.resize(newsize)

# Shows the image in image viewer
img.show()
    
X = image.img_to_array(img)
X = np.expand_dims(X,axis = 0)
images = np.vstack([X])
val = model.predict(images)
if val == 0:
    print("Pasta")

elif val == 1:
    print("Pizza")
```

Comment: Recommend just printing `val` without the `if-else`, and seeing the format, e.g. you could be getting a probability instead of a 0/1. Once you have that, you can make any required adjustments so that your `if-else` works.

Answer (score 0):

`model.predict()` returns a float between [0, 1] when the model's output uses sigmoid activation function. It will almost never return 0 or 1. You need to round your predictions with something like `np.rint()` and check *that* value, assuming a balanced training set of classes during training, some adjustments may need to be made to the actual prediction.

```
val = model.predict(images)
val = np.rint(val)
if val == 0:
    print("Pasta")

elif val == 1:
    print("Pizza")
```